# Highstock displayed inconsistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I'm working on a website where I'm using HighStock. The site was working fine and then I went away for a few hours. When I came back the chart would only display one datapoint.

Looking in the code with Chrome there were no errors and the datpoints had been printed by the PHP correctly.

By a coincidence, I noticed when resized the window it would suddenly display correctly. The only thing that's changing on resize in my CSS is the containers width (parent of the chart div).

I tried taking just a few of my datapoints into a HighStock example on JsFiddle, there I see no datapoints. https://jsfiddle.net/p9jqvw41/

```
    Highcharts.stockChart('chart2', {

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
        data: "[1574880360000,9],[1574876760000,10],[1574873160000,10]",
        type: 'spline',
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
});
```

I also tried:

- Using a proxy to visit my site, then It's displayed
  correctly. (So I guess It has to be a local error?)
- Using a different browser, displayed incorrectly.
- Clearing Cache, still incorrectly displayed.

The only thing that would seem reasonable is that I've reached some limited number of calls to HighStock, but even that isn't consistent with some of the mentioned above.

I feel like I'm going nuts so any help would be very appreciated.
[image: JsFiddle result]
[image: Displayed correctly after resize]
[image: Displayed incorrectly]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I had data in Descending order instead of Ascending, probably stopped working after update to Highchart.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I wanted to ask about. In the example which you shared are two mistakes. First - data should be an array of values or array of objects or array of arrays, but in your example is a string. Second - with corrected data, you can find the error in the console which should guide you what was wrong with your data. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1knd85fm/